# Storing multiple object types in a List

Tags: java

I have following homework about computer store:

1. There are several class include: Monitor, Case, Mouse, Keyboard.
2. All the classes have common fields: id, name, price, quantity.
3. Each class has some unique fields.
   All most features are: add, update, delete, find, show list, save, load file

   -So, first I will create a class named Product have 4 common fields. Above classes will extends from Product.

   -Then, I think I maybe create a ComputerStore class which have a field is items type ArrayList. items stores all objects which are instance of 4 above classes  But I'm not sure.

   Whether it is reasonable? I need some ideas

Before , I always use ArrayList store for only one class like

```
List <String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Now they are multi type. I think it's generic in Java, right??

In case, I want to update for 1 items. I must think about how to change information for them. Ex: mouse for some code, keyboard for another code. Anyway, thank for everybody!

Comment: It's reasonable. Now write it :)

Comment: Man, look at these answers; nobody likes just giving hints these days.

Comment: So what is the closest common supertype between your multiple classes?

Answer (score 4):

Your approach is 100% reasonable.

You are completely on the right track with "generics". First, check out the official [enter link description here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html).

Next, just think about your data in real world terms, like you are already doing: Monitor, case, mouse, and keyboard are products. Your computer store's inventory is a list of products.

Hint: A list of products.

Put that together with what you learn about generics through that tutorial, and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 2):

You could use java generic.First create a java collection (ex: List) with supper class type, **Product**. Now you could add any sub classes (**Monitor** , **Keyboard** etc) in your collection (List) that extends of class **Product**.

```
public class Product{

}
public class Monitor extends Product{

}

public class Keyboard extends Product{

}

List<Product> products = new ArrayList<Product>();
products.add(new Monitor());
products.add(new Keyboard());
```

Comment: Correct example & style.  The comment about 'autoboxing' is not technically correct, 'boxing' actually refers to wrapping _primitives_ (such as `int`) into their object equivalent (`Integer` in this case).

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a superclass (Product), you can have the list's type as Product, i.e.

```
List<Product> list = new ArrayList<Product>();
list.add(new Mouse());
list.add(new Keyboard());
```

It will allow you to iterate them and list their name and price without caring for the class, but if you intend to take an item out of the list you'll need to check its actual type (depending on what you do with it).

Comment: In an application like this, a reasonably well-designed base class would eliminate most, if not all, of the need to explicitly check an object's type.

Comment: Yep. The base class should have Price & Description, so processing should not need to know specifics. This is the point of abstraction.

Comment: You make a lot of assumptions about what he's going to do with the objects inside the list. I have 15 years of Java under my belt, but I'm still not a clairvoyant.

Comment: And the years-of-experience card comes out.

Comment: @JasonC No, but my "depending on what you do with it" disclaimer was meant to address that. If you're merely iterating the prices then you're golden, but it seems that he'll be doing other things with the classes as well (since they have their own additional properties).

Comment: Thanks @Kayaman, not a bad answer. I don't always get this right first time myself -- but OO design suggests that variability of behavior by object-type, be implemented in the design by overriding/implementing methods. As a pithy example, `Product.packForShipping (IShippingBuilder shipping)` could build & address one or more packages, each within weight & size limits, with an appropriate number of products in each.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do like below**

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Test{
public static void main(String... args){
    List<MultiObj> multiObjs = new ArrayList();

    MultiObj ob = new MultiObj(); multiObjs.add(ob);
    ResX xOb = new ResX(); multiObjs.add(xOb);
    ResY yOb = new ResY(); multiObjs.add(yOb);
    ResZ zOb = new ResZ(); multiObjs.add(zOb);

    for (int i = 0; i < multiObjs.size(); i++ ) {
        System.out.println(multiObjs.get(i).getV());
    }
    System.out.println("Waoo its working");
 }
}
class MultiObj{
public String greet(){
    return "Hello World";
}
public String getV(){
    return "Hello World";
 }
}
class ResX extends MultiObj{
String x = "ResX";
public String getX(){
    return x;
}
public String getV(){
    return x;
 }
}
class ResY extends MultiObj{
String y = "ResY";
public String getY(){
    return y;
}
public String getV(){
    return y;
 }
}
class ResZ extends MultiObj{
String z = "ResZ";
public String getZ(){
    return z;
}
public String getV(){
    return z;
 }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

You could do this:

```
public class Item {

public Item(int id, string name, float price, int amount, int ArrayID) {
if (ArrayID == 1) { 
ID1 = id;
name1 = name;
price1 = price;
amount1 = amount;
}
if (ArrayID == 2) { 
ID2 = id;
name2 = name;
price2 = price;
amount2 = amount;
}
if (ArrayID == 3) { 
ID3 = id;
name3 = name;
price3 = price;
amount3 = amount;
}
if (ArrayID == 4) { 
ID4 = id;
name4 = name;
price4 = price;
amount4 = amount;
}

}

//ArrayID #1
public static int ID1;
public static String name1;
public static float price1;
public static int amount1;

//ArrayID #2
public static int ID2;
public static String name2;
public static float price2;
public static int amount2;

//ArrayID #3
public static int ID3;
public static String name3;
public static float price3;
public static int amount3;

//ArrayID #4
public static int ID4;
public static String name4;
public static float price4;
public static int amount4;


public static int[] id = ID1, ID2 ID3, ID4;
//so forth...
}
```

Comment: This entirely misses the point of arrays & objects. This is a failure in any programming language -- Java back thru PHP, GW-BASIC, even back to FORTRAN.